# Error al conectar Netbeans con una base de datos de SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, netbeans, jdbc

Buenas, estoy queriendo conectar Netbeans con una base de datos pero tengo el siguiente error

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://CRONOPIO:1433;databaseName=ppm using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (No se pudo realizar la conexión TCP/IP al host CRONOPIO, puerto 1433. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto.".)

Mi SQL Server no tiene ninguna instancia, pero la base de datos existe y mi puerto esta activado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que se me ocurre, ya que probé varias cosas, es que quizás al no tener un nombre de instancia el campo vació sea lo que me genera el error. 
Saludos.

Comment: El error te dice claramente que no puede conectarse a SQL vía TCP/IP. Asegurate que el SQL tenga habilitada la interfaz TCP/IP y que no haya un firewall bloqueando la conexión al puerto 1433. O cambia tu cadena de conexión para utilizar otro protocolo, por ejemplo, named pipes.

Comment: _Mi SQL Server no tiene ninguna instancia_ querrás decir que no tiene una instancia con nombre, pero instancia tiene, sino no existiría. Probá poner en el nombre de la instancia el host donde está el servidor SQL. Si es la misma máquina, poné **localhost** o **CRONOPIO** como aparece en la imagen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debes ir al administrador de configuración de `SQL Server`.

En donde escoges la configuración de red de `SQL Server` y los protocolos de tu instancia en donde te aparecerán la lista de protocolos, seleccionas `TCP/IP` te aparecerá una ventana y escoges la pestaña de direcciones `IP`.

Luego asignas a los puertos `TCP` y a los puertos dinámicos `TCP` el puerto **1433** de tu respectiva dirección IP, reinicia tu servidor. Luego de esto intenta conectarte nuevamente con tu base de datos. Si te sirvió no te olvides de aprobar mi respuesta. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no hay puertos asignados a IP1, IP2, etc se debe usar el que está en la opción "IPALL" que se encuentra haciendo scrolling más abajo de "Propiedades: TCP/IP".

Answer (score 1):

Hace poco trabaje con SQLServer en Spring Boot en arranque con Jetty y me daba el mismo error. Mi solución fue la siguiente, ir a la ventana de:

> Sql Server Configuration Manager/ Configuración de red de SQL Server/ Protocolos de MSSQLSERVER.

[image: Ir a TCP/IP]

y todo los que esta con `Habilitado` seleccionar el ComboBox y colocarlo en `SI`.
**Nota:** Si no sabes que direcciones IP están asociadas a tu configuración de la instacia colocar `SI` a todos sin excepción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Los puertos TCP y puertos dinámicos TCP deben estar en el puerto 1433, luego en el sql server, clic derecho y restaura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]